# Flash FLVPlayback states

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, flvplayback

I'm writing my own class to manage a skin for an FLVPlayback component. It works 90% of the time, but sometimes the state get really messed up. Specifically, the video is playing, meaning I can see it play and the VideoEvent.PLAYHEAD_UPDATE event is firing, but when I poll the FLVPlayback component about its playing property, it returns false. Instead the buffering state is set to true.

I assume this may be because 'buffering' is kind of a subset of 'playing', but I cannot confirm this in the documentation. I guess another way to ask this question is, "Does the FLVPlayback component ever buffer while it is in a stopped state?"

Comment: I think I've confirmed that a buffering state implies a playing state as well, but would like to see this in the documentation. Also, if the FLVPlayback ever finds itself buffering while the video is paused (or stopped) I'm not sure how my skin will react.

Answer (score 0):

Buffering can occur in the playing or paused state.  I don't believe it occurs in the stopped state.